# How does a Microsoft-accountless BitLocker encryption scheme work?

Tags: windows-10, encryption, fedora, bitlocker

I have a new Dell XPS 15 (7590). I did not give the initial Windows 10 Home setup any wifi information so I could install Windows with a pure local user account--there is no Microsoft account on my computer.

I then installed Fedora 31, as one does, and was surprised to see that the main data partition is encrypted by BitLocker! I can't decrypt it with [dislocker](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker) as I don't know how it was encrypted to begin with.

When I boot the machine, I reach the Windows 10 login screen without entering any passwords to decrypt the drive (as I have to do when booting into my Fedora 31 partition, which is encrypted by LUKS): the only password I enter is for my local user account.

I'd love to know what my recovery key is, or password!, so I can decrypt the drive from within Fedora to mount it. But Windows 10 Home shouldn't support BitLocker, and Microsoft's documentation seems to imply that you can't use BitLocker without a Microsoft account--that's where the recovery password gets stored.

`manage-bde` almost implies that the drive *isn't* encrypted, but the Windows Disk Manager (and gparted) are quite clear that the C: partition is encrypted. Explorer does not show the usual BitLocker icons, nor does it offer the Manage Bitlocker option.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> manage-bde -status c:
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.18362
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Volume C: [OS]
[OS Volume]

    Size:                 765.15 GB
    BitLocker Version:    2.0
    Conversion Status:    Used Space Only Encrypted
    Percentage Encrypted: 100.0%
    Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128
    Protection Status:    Protection Off
    Lock Status:          Unlocked
    Identification Field: Unknown
    Key Protectors:       None Found
```

Has anyone encountered this before? I'd love to keep the encryption on the drive, it appears that a `manage-bde -off C:` will permanently decrypt a drive in Windows 10 Home, but I don't know how the drive got encrypted or where the recovery keys are stored.

Comment: You can definitely use Bitlocker without a microsoft account.

Comment: *"Windows 10 Home shouldn't support BitLocker"* - true but all editions can support [Device Encryption](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4502379/windows-10-device-encryption) if your device meets requirements.  See [How To Enable Device Encryption on Windows 10 (Home & All Editions)](https://windowsloop.com/enable-device-encryption-windows-10/)

Comment: The device in question is using Device Encryption not BitLocker if Windows 10 Home is actually installed. It is not possible for BitLocker protection to be enabled on Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Oh, curious. So there's a similar-but-different encryption scheme in Windows? Is it enabled by default in new Windows installations when the device supports it?

Comment: See the [difference between BitLocker and Device Encryption](https://theintercept.com/2015/12/28/recently-bought-a-windows-computer-microsoft-probably-has-your-encryption-key/) (the new technology). Device encryption is activated before the computer is sold and the key is shared with MS, MS is a key escrow and you have no choice. See also [BitLocker device encryption requires giving Microsoft your recovery key (unless you're in a domain)](https://tinyapps.org/blog/201509210700_bitlocker_requires_microsoft_account.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BitLocker has never depended on a Microsoft account. It is only a *possible* location for storing the recovery password, but not the only one (the same password can be stored on Active Directory, or in a plain text file of your choosing) – and a BitLocker drive doesn't necessarily have a recovery password to begin with.

You can run **`manage-bde c: -protectors -get`** to see what unlock mechanisms are available. Whenever a recovery password is present, it will be shown directly in the protectors list.

But in your case, the status output immediately says that there are none: the disk's master key is simply stored on the disk itself, giving you no protection at all.

This means BitLocker is only being used with the expectation for you to manually activate it later on – whenever you decide to do so, Windows will not need to spend time encrypting gigabytes of actual data, it will simply encrypt the master key. That's when BitLocker will prompt you to save the recovery password, too.

Dislocker should be able to access the drive using the `--clearkey` option.

---

Also for future reference:

Commonly the passwordless unlocking is implemented by using a TPM, which holds the key in a separate chip and only gives it to the OS if the entire boot process exactly matches its requirements. (That is, if you boot e.g. Linux on the same computer, the boot log will result in a different PCR hash and the TPM-sealed key will not be retrievable.)

If your disk actually had e.g. TPM protection enabled but did not have a recovery key, you could add one using `manage-bde c: -protectors -add -recoverypassword`.

(Alternatively, you can add a recovery *key file* using the `-recoverykey` option and use it with Dislocker's `--bekfile=`.)

However, again, in your case there is no "main" protector added yet. So if you want to protect the data, you should instead start by adding a `-tpm` or `-password` protector, then add a recovery key as the second option.

Comment: @EricLawler - Your drive currently doesn’t appear to be encrypted.  The protection status clearly indicates that Device Encryption is turned off.  If you were to resume the protection, you would be asked to backup your Recovery Key, there isn’t a way to enable FDE using Device Encryption or BitLocker without being promoted to backup the Recovery Key.

Comment: @Ramhound: Uh, where do you see that "Device Encryption is turned off" exactly?

Comment: Protection Status:    **Protection Off** and Lock Status:          **Unlocked** I question if it’s even Device Encryption since that typically is only enabled by default on Windows 10 tablets.  The device in question isn’t a tablet.  Device Encryption by default stores the recovery key to your Microsoft Account, but on a local account, the user should have had to specifically enable it.  However, a question if this isn’t actually BitLocker and the author is mistaken about Windows 10 Home being installed.

Comment: That means the key is unprotected. The data on the disk is still encrypted.

Comment: Your right; I was reading that result wrong